# Text selection and bubble overlay as Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-tooltip

I am looking for a way to select text on a website in Chrome and have a overlay/tooltip pop with content depending on the text selection.

Has anyone done this before or knows from the top of their heads how to make the toolip pop-up?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

All you need to do is listen for mouse events:

- mousedown: to hide the bubble.
- mouseup: to show the bubble.

For example, this might help you get started. More tweaks are needed, to figure out if you initiated the selection from down->up, right->left, etc (all directions). You can use the following code as a startup:

**contentscript.js**

```
// Add bubble to the top of the page.
var bubbleDOM = document.createElement('div');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('class', 'selection_bubble');
document.body.appendChild(bubbleDOM);

// Lets listen to mouseup DOM events.
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    renderBubble(e.clientX, e.clientY, selection);
  }
}, false);


// Close the bubble when we click on the screen.
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}, false);

// Move that bubble to the appropriate location.
function renderBubble(mouseX, mouseY, selection) {
  bubbleDOM.innerHTML = selection;
  bubbleDOM.style.top = mouseY + 'px';
  bubbleDOM.style.left = mouseX + 'px';
  bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

**contentscript.css**

```
.selection_bubble {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2e88c4), to(#075698));
}
```

**manifest.json**

Change the matches portion to the domain you want to inject these content scripts.

```
...
...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": ["main.css"],
      "js": ["main.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
...
...
```

If you want to style it to look like a bubble, Nicolas Gallagher did some awesome CSS3 [demos](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/) for bubbles!

Comment: Your Chrome Extension answers are fantastic, and way too little upvoted. Once I can assign the bounty (after 24 hrs), you'll get it all. Many thanks!

Comment: @BartKiers Ah thanks, it is okay, I do this cause I love helping people where I can! I learned by using StackOverflow and reading documentations a lot :)

Comment: I don't know how to add the last one into manifest.json... It says `content_scripts` is invalid.

Comment: Put it on a blog or github etc. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something similar to what you're asking about.  I listened for the user to select text and when there was a selection, I displayed a list of links for things like "Note on Facebook", "Define", etc.

A day or two after I started to write it, I found that google was going to add context menu support in a future release so I didn't touch this until recently (when I converted to context menus).

Take a look at the code:

http://code.google.com/p/select-actions/source/browse/trunk/select_actions.js?r=4

Comment: Also, I should mention that most people would uninstall my extension immediately because they're afraid of the security message about content scripts having access to information on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody provides a better answer then you might look at how [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) extension does it (it would be hard as its code is minimized).