# Get highlighted text, count it, take it to popup. Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, tooltip

Guys, I'm doing Chrome extension and I need:

1. Get highligheted text;
2. Count it and edit number in real-time;
3. Get this number in popup or tooltip over mouse for 1 or few seconds.
4. Maybe will have a limitation of characters like 3 or 4-digits numbers.

Please, need your help.

What I`ve got with Google and others:

For (1) I need this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getSelection")
  sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
else
  sendResponse({}); // snub them. });
```

Am I right?

For (2) I think I'd use String length but I don`t understand how it`ll get text from (1) and how send it to (3).
And where'd I paste limitation code for (4)?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you state put this number over the mouse for 1 or 2 seconds. You can do the entire thing in the [content-script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) the code you stated. Then you can add a bubble overlay to show the number:

[Text selection and bubble overlay as Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409378/text-selection-and-bubble-overlay-as-chrome-extension/4414762#4414762)