# Text selection and bubble overlay as browser extension on mobile phones

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, translation, overlay

I'm trying to do something similar to what is described here: [Text selection and bubble overlay as Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409378/text-selection-and-bubble-overlay-as-chrome-extension)

I need this for a translator extension. The Deepl Translator chrome extension is exactly what I am looking for, but it's desktop only: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cofdbpoegempjloogbagkncekinflcnj

But I need to to work on mobile phones. Because my idea for the extension is, that language students can use it to lookup unknown vocabulary. Many language students have limited or no access to a desktop computer.

How do I go about developing something like this? I haven't actually seen any browser extensions on mobile phones, they usually only work on desktop.

Also if something like this already exist, could you let me know about it?

I looked for something suitable on the chrome webstore, but only found options for desktop. Also on google playstore I couldn't find anything like this. All apps I found were completely separate from the browser, so you have to copy/paste each time you need something translated, which is very tedious.